# phpMyAdmin acess denied locally using MAMP on mac

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I have downloaded MAMP and started my servers, however when I click on my phpMyAdmin I get this error:

I used MAMP like a year ago with no problems, and I have tried to delete everything and reinstall etc, but I still get this issue.

What can I do? I need to get into phpMyAdmin to create a database etc so I can setup wordpress locally.

[image]

Comment: "rejected the connection" means either mysql isn't running, isn't on the port phpmyadmin's trying to use, or the port is firewalled somehow.

Comment: Use mysqlworkbench to confirm your mysql install is correct and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the preferences pane of MAMP switch back to PHP 5.6.10.